# getting data from upload-template in jquery file upload plugin

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-file-upload

I tried to use ASP.NET MVC 3 example of jquery file upload plugin. I've changed upload-template that it shows an input filed and a checkbox for every file (user can set some data for each chosen file). And now when user decides to upload file I need to get not only data provided by plugin (file name, file url, file size) but also data from input and checkbox. But I don't know how to get values when user uploads many files, because if I give an id to these fields there will be the same id for each input and each checkbox, so it's not gonna work. If I give the same class for these fields I can get elements by class and iterate through these fields but I don't know which iteration refers to which file. 
I've put hidden inputs in form which is send when file is uploaded but I have no idea how to get data from each input in upload-template to send it via form.

There is a code used to display each file added to queue but not uploaded yet.

```
<!-- The template to display files available for upload -->
<script id="template-upload" type="text/x-tmpl">
{% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
    {% var nodeName = file.name.substring(0, file.name.length - 4); %}
    <tr class="template-upload fade">
        **<td><input id="setNodeName" value="{%=nodeName%}" type="text" class="form-control nodename" /></td>**
        {% if (file.error) { %}
            <td class="error" colspan="2"><span class="label label-important">{%=locale.fileupload.error%}</span> {%=locale.fileupload.errors[file.error] || file.error%}</td>
        {% } else if (o.files.valid && !i) { %}
            <td>
                <div class="progress progress-success progress-striped active"><div class="bar" style="width:0%;"></div></div>
            </td>
            <td class="start">{% if (!o.options.autoUpload) { %}
                <button class="btn btn-primary">
                    <i class="icon-upload icon-white"></i>
                    <span>{%=locale.fileupload.start%}</span>
                </button>
            {% } %}</td>
        {% } else { %}
            <td colspan="2"></td>
        {% } %}
        <td class="cancel">{% if (!i) { %}
            <button class="btn btn-warning">
                <i class="icon-ban-circle icon-white"></i>
                <span>{%=locale.fileupload.cancel%}</span>
            </button>
        {% } %}</td>
    </tr>
{% } %}
</script>
```

Then there is form which is send when file is uploaded. I added here hidden input to store data from user (input filed which has id setNodeName):

```
<form id="fileupload" action="@Url.Action("UploadFiles")" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    **<input type="hidden" id="nodename" value="" />**
        <!-- The fileupload-buttonbar contains buttons to add/delete files and start/cancel the upload -->
        <div class="row fileupload-buttonbar">
            <div class="span7">
                <!-- The fileinput-button span is used to style the file input field as button -->
                <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
                    <i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i>
                    <span>Add files...</span>
                    <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
                </span>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary start">
                    <i class="icon-upload icon-white"></i>
                    <span>Start upload</span>
                </button>
                <button type="reset" class="btn btn-warning cancel">
                    <i class="icon-ban-circle icon-white"></i>
                    <span>Cancel upload</span>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete">
                    <i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i>
                    <span>Delete</span>
                </button>
                <input type="checkbox" class="toggle">
            </div>
            <div class="span5">
                <!-- The global progress bar -->
                <div class="progress progress-success progress-striped active fade">
                    <div class="bar" style="width:0%;"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- The loading indicator is shown during image processing -->
        <div class="fileupload-loading"></div>
        <br>
        <!-- The table listing the files available for upload/download -->
        <table class="table table-striped"><tbody class="files" data-toggle="modal-gallery" data-target="#modal-gallery"></tbody></table>
    </form>
```

And in the function called before the file is uploaded I wanted to transfer data from input in upload-template to hidden input in form. And as I said I tried to call it by id but when there is more than one file I have a couple of inputs with the same id so it's not working. I also tried to get elements by class (I changed setnodename id to setnodename class) and I had a couple of inputs with data from user but I didn't know which of these inputs should I use at the moment because files in jquery plugin don't have index value. So for each uploaded file I had an array of inputs (count of inputs was equal to added files count) but I didn't know which of array elements is valid for file which was uploaded at the moment.

Comment: Could you post some code snippets of what you tried?

Comment: @Oleksii Aza I've added some code, but it's hard to show something as I'm looking for an idea rather than code improvement.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take a look at the [documentation of plugin about sending additional parameters with file](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/How-to-submit-additional-Form-Data). What you would need to do is to add event handler on 'fileuploadsubmit' which will fire on every file before it uploads:

```
$('#fileupload').bind('fileuploadsubmit', function (e, data) {
    var inputs = data.context.find(':input');
    data.formData = inputs.serializeArray();
})
```